# MacOS 10.15.4 automatic eject sdcard when goes to sleep

Tags: macos, mac, catalina, sd-card

I bought a transcent jet lite sd card for my macbook pro mid 2014. On MacOS 10.15.4 whenever my macbook goes to sleep my sd card automatically ejected and there is no device in disk utility to mount again and I had to physically put sd card again and it's annoying.

I tried these but none of them solve my problem.

1. Reset SMC
2. uncheck put hard drives sleep in energy saver
3. Install Mountain App
4. Installing jetdrive toolbox and turn it on

Comment: This probably won't help but it might. Try running First Aid on the SD and make sure it is in HFS or APFS. Sometimes Mac computers can act up with NTFS, FAT, FAT32, and ExFAT drives. Try checking if the issue is there in Safe Mode. That will determine whether it is a third-party application tampering with the settings or not.

Comment: I forgot to include this but here's a link on Safe Mode: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262

Comment: I've had USB drives automatically eject from my MacBook every time it goes to sleep for a while now, I think at least since 10.13.

Comment: @Todd my sd card is HFS+ but surprisingly I dont have this problem in safe mode how can i figure out which application cause this problem ?

Comment: @At0mic for usb check this out [fix-usb](https://github.com/syscl/Fix-usb-sleep)

Comment: @Siyanew First try uninstalling third-party anti malware and apps such as Clean My Mac X.

Comment: @Todd I uninstalled clean my mac and any suspicious app and restart but nothing changed.

Comment: @Siyanew Try installing Malwarebytes and scanning for Malware. If there is none or the issue persists, check for suspicious files. Also, if nothing works, then you can try reinstalling macOS without losing data from macOS Recovery. See the link for more: https://support.apple.com/en-ca/guide/mac-help/mchlp1599/mac.

Comment: @Todd I did what you said I install Malwarebytes and Kaspersky but none of them find anything. reinstall mac didn't solve the issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I found what my problem it is I open console.app and filter with `/dev/disk2` and found out transcend helper eject my disk so I uninstall app and delete helper tools and then **reboot**.

Command to delete transcend helper tools:

```
sudo rm /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.transcend.TSSleepHandlerHelp.plist
sudo rm /Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.transcend.TSSleepHandlerHelp
```

Comment: I don't know if this helps but I found these in my system too, leftover from when I used the Transcend microSD card expansion. So thanks.

Comment: I greatly appreciate you taking the time to share your experience, @JoshuaPinter.